# Assign list without reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variable-assignment

Let's see an example,

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = list1
```

then I append in `list1`

```
list1.append(1)
list1.append(2)
list1.append(3)
```

then `list1` will look like

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]
```

and `list2` will also look like the same

```
list2 = ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]
```

this happens because python assign list by reference not by value. I want to prevent this, and I want after all this happens my both list looks like below:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3]
list2 = list.copy()
```

This will work.